# SQL Query Copy values - Beginner

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

```
INSERT INTO Odds_display (Team, Odds)
SELECT DISTINCT Team1, Odds1
FROM Odds
WHERE Team1 = 'Team SoloMid'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Team FROM Odds_display)
```

So, I don't know if I'm blind or stupid... Or maybe both! Kind of a beginner to SQL but what I m aiming for here is to copy 2 values from a table and insert them into another table but don't insert any duplicates!

So the table Odds is the `"original"` table and I want to copy to the `Odds_display` table and prevent duplicates!

Comment: Apoligize for the formatting. It looked good when I posted it :(

Comment: Use the `{ }` tool to mark code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause in your subquery to tell it which team you don't want to create a duplicate of

```
INSERT INTO Odds_display (Team, Odds)
SELECT DISTINCT Team1, Odds1
FROM Odds
WHERE Team1 = 'Team SoloMid'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Odds_display WHERE Team = 'Team SoloMid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `NOT EXISTS` to `NOT IN` as below

```
INSERT INTO Odds_display (Team, Odds)
SELECT DISTINCT Team1, Odds1
FROM Odds
WHERE Team1 = 'Team SoloMid'
AND Team1 NOT IN (SELECT Team FROM Odds_display)
```